# R: How to use qqplot() instead of qqPlot() ? (What's the 2nd paramter?)

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution, quantile

This is a simple question, but I've spent way too much time looking for the answer.

With qqPlot() from the car package, this command produces a graph you can use to check normality:

```
qqPlot(x)
```

Where x is a vector.
What is the command using qqplot() from base to produce the same graph? (I think it won't have the nice outlier shading area that the car version does, unfortunately).

The command wants two inputs, and the documentation isn't helpful (for me, anyway).

The reason I'm asking it there's a requirement that I re-scale the x-axis. When I searched for how to do that, I found a post that says the car package version doesn't allow that, and to use qqplot() instead.  I found what I needed to set the axis, but now I need to know what to use as that 2nd parameter (to generate the appropriate comparison distribution).

Answer (score 2):

I have always used `qqnorm()` with `qqline()` in base R to produce qqplots. Maybe this is all you need?

```
x <- rnorm(30)
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x)
```

In the documentation for qqplot(), the second parameter is a list of values selected randomly from a given distribution. In the example in the documentation, they use random values from a t-distribution, `qqplot(y, rt(300, df=5))`. This is similar to my example above, where `rnorm(30)` generates a random list of values from the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The base function `qqplot(x, y)` is effectively shorthand for `plot(sort(x), sort(y))` (at least where `x` and `y` are the same length). This allows a visual check of whether x and y come from a similar shaped distribution. It's not the same as `qqPlot` from `car`, which takes a single vector `x` and plots its sorted values against a vector of quantiles from a normal distribution.

Suppose we have a vector `x` like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
x <- rnorm(100)
```

Then we can do

```r
qqPlot(x)
```

[image]

But the points on this plot are the same on those we would get with:

```
plot(qnorm(ppoints(x)), sort(x))
```

[image]

The base R function that is equivalent to `qqPlot` is not `qqplot`, but `qqnorm`. The reason for the difference in naming is that `qqPlot` can check other distributions too, not just the normal distribution.

So the solution in base R is just:

```r
qqnorm(x)
```

[image]